# Data binding for dynamically generated HTML in Polymer?

Tags: polymer

When I write the following inside my `<template>`-tag, everything works fine:

```
<ul id="breadcrumbList" class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a on-click="{{breadcrumbClick}}">{{overviewName}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

I dynamically generated a new `<li>`-element of the same structure, like this:

```
crumb = document.createElement("li");
crumb.innerHTML = '<a on-click="{{breadcrumbClick}}">'+category+'</a>';
```

But when I click this element, the event-handler isn't called.

The event-handler looks like this:

```
breadcrumbClick: function(event, detail, sender) {
     /*reaction*/
}
```

I did not find any documentation about whether it's possible or impossible to use data binding for dynamically generated content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with `injectBoundHTML()`. We haven't documented it yet, but you can see the method signature and demo here: https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/607

Example:

```
<li id="myli></li>

this.injectBoundHTML('<a on-click="{{breadcrumbClick}}">...</a>', this.$.myli);
```

Comment: injectBoundHTML isn't available anymore in Polymer 1.0

Comment: Here is an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836412/polymer-1-0-injectboundhtml-alternative